# Calculate total from values stored in Firebase-Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a total from numbers stored by the user on a cloud Firestore database. There will be a varying amount of values, depending on how many items the user adds to the sub collection.

What I cannot seem to figure out is how to "pick-up the values (`itemCost` on the database) and add them together to then display as a total cost. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've included the code for the activity (where I'm currently writing my database query), the List adapter that serves this activity, the model class that generates the view and finally, a screenshot of the firebase path. Hope that helps:

[image]

This is the Activity:

```
public class UsersMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "UserMenuActivity";
public static String finalId;
public static int totalCalsToPass;
public Context umContext;
public String venueId;
public Button myButton;
public int totalCalsData;
public int totalCals = 0;
Toolbar menuToolbar;
private FirebaseFirestore umFirestore;
private FirebaseAuth umFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private RecyclerView umRecyclerView;
private List<UserMenu> userMenu;
private View.OnClickListener umClickListener;
private UserMenuListAdapter userMenuListAdapter;
private String getUserId;
private TextView passedCalContent;
//FOR THE CAL COUNT
private List<UserMenu> calsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_users_menu );

    menuToolbar = findViewById( R.id.menu_toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( menuToolbar );

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( false );
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled( false );
    }

    myButton = findViewById( R.id.remove_button );

    userMenu = new ArrayList<>();
    userMenuListAdapter = new UserMenuListAdapter( getApplicationContext(), userMenu, umClickListener );

    umRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById( R.id.user_menu_recycler_view );
    umRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );
    umRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( this ) );
    umRecyclerView.setAdapter( userMenuListAdapter );

    passedCalContent = findViewById( R.id.users_menu_calories_set );
    passedCalContent.setText( valFromAct1 );

    umFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    umFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    getUserId = Objects.requireNonNull( umFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() ).getUid();


    CollectionReference userMenuRef = umFirestore.collection( "AppUsers" )
            .document( getUserId )
            .collection( "UserMenu" );


    userMenuRef.limit( 100 ).addSnapshotListener( (documentSnapshots, e) -> {

        if (e != null) {
            Log.d( TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage() );

        }
        assert documentSnapshots != null;
        for (DocumentChange doc : Objects.requireNonNull( documentSnapshots ).getDocumentChanges()) {
            UserMenu menu = doc.getDocument().toObject( UserMenu.class ).withId( doc.getDocument().getId() );

            Log.d( TAG, doc.getDocument().getId() + " => " + doc.getDocument() );

            finalId = doc.getDocument().getId();
            userMenu.add( menu );
            userMenuListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } );

//Method here to calculate the total cals value to show in header???
    calsList = new ArrayList<>();
    totalCalsData = calsList.size();
    totalCals = 0;


    Query calorieRef = umFirestore.collection( "AppUsers" )
            .document( getUserId )
            .collection( "UserMenu" ).whereEqualTo( "itemCals", true );

    calorieRef.limit( 15 ).addSnapshotListener( (QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) -> {

        if (e != null) {
            Log.d( TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d( TAG, "Success: " + getUserId);
        }

        assert documentSnapshots != null;
        for (DocumentChange calDoc : Objects.requireNonNull( documentSnapshots ).getDocumentChanges()) {
            UserMenu mMenu = calDoc.getDocument().toObject( UserMenu.class ).withId( calDoc.getDocument().getId() );

            calsList.add( mMenu );

            for (int i = 0; i < calsList.size(); i++) {
                totalCals = totalCals + Integer.parseInt( String.valueOf( calsList.get( i ) ) );
            }
            totalCalsToPass = Integer.parseInt( String.valueOf( totalCals ) );

        }

    } );
}
```

This is the adapter

```
import static com.melcolton.bite.UsersMenuActivity.finalId;
```

public class UserMenuListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private static final String TAG = "Adapter Log";
private View.OnClickListener myClickListener;
private FirebaseFirestore fbFirestore;
private FirebaseAuth fbAuth;

public String fbUserId;
public List<UserMenu> userMenu;
public Context context;

public UserMenuListAdapter(Context context, List<UserMenu> userMenu, View.OnClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    this.userMenu =  userMenu ;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserMenuListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Context context = parent.getContext();
    View menuView = LayoutInflater.from( context ).inflate( R.layout.item_confirm_list_element, parent, false );
    return new ViewHolder( menuView, myClickListener );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserMenuListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fbFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    fbUserId = fbAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = holder;

        holder.userMenuName.setText( userMenu.get( position ).getItemName() );
        holder.userMenuDesc.setText( userMenu.get( position ).getItemDesc() );
        holder.userMenuCals.setText( userMenu.get( position ).getItemCals().toString() );
        holder.userMenuCost.setText( userMenu.get( position ).getItemCost().toString() );

        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText( context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


                fbFirestore.collection( "AppUsers" ).document(fbUserId).collection( "UserMenu" ).document(finalId)
                        .delete().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        userMenu.remove( position );
                        notifyItemRemoved( position );
                        notifyItemRangeChanged( position, userMenu.size() );
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        holder.menuView.setVisibility( View.GONE );

                    }
                } );

            }

        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return userMenu.size();
}

public void onEvent (QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e !=null) {
        Log.w( TAG, "onEvent error: ",e );
        onError (e);
    }
}

private void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    Log.w( TAG, "onEvent error: ",e );
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CardView userMenuCardView;
    public TextView userMenuName;
    public TextView userMenuDesc;
    public TextView userMenuCals;
    public TextView userMenuCost;
    public Button deleteButton;
    View menuView;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView, View.OnClickListener myClickListener) {
        super( itemView );
        itemView.setOnClickListener( myClickListener );
        menuView = itemView;

        userMenuCardView = menuView.findViewById( R.id.user_menu_cardview );
        userMenuName = menuView.findViewById( R.id.txt_cart_item_name );
        userMenuDesc = menuView.findViewById( R.id.txt_cart_item_desc );
        userMenuCals = menuView.findViewById( R.id.txt_cart_item_cals );
        userMenuCost = menuView.findViewById( R.id.txt_cart_item_cost );
        deleteButton = menuView.findViewById( R.id.remove_button );
    }
}
```

}

And finally the model class

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.IgnoreExtraProperties;
```

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class UserMenu extends UserId {

```
private String ItemName;
private String ItemDesc;
private Long ItemCals;
private Double ItemCost;
private String itemId;

public UserMenu() {

}

public UserMenu(String itemName, String itemDesc, Long itemCals, Double itemCost) {
    ItemName = itemName;
    ItemDesc = itemDesc;
    ItemCals = itemCals;
    ItemCost = itemCost;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return ItemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    ItemName = itemName;
}

public String getItemDesc() {
    return ItemDesc;
}

public void setItemDesc(String itemDesc) {
    ItemDesc = itemDesc;
}

public Long getItemCals() {
    return ItemCals;
}

public void setItemCals(Long itemCals) {
    ItemCals = itemCals;
}

public Double getItemCost() {
    return ItemCost;
}

public void setItemCost(Double itemCost) {
    ItemCost = itemCost;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the total that you are talking about, please use the following code:

```
userMenuRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            double total = 0;
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                double itemCost = document.getDouble("itemCost");
                total += itemCost;
            }
            Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(total));
        }
    }
});
```

The output will be the sum of all `itemCost` property that exist in your documents.

Another approach would be to keep a running total over time, as each new price is known. Then, you can query for that running total in another document when you need it.

Comment: Alex thankyou so much. I'm feeling kinda sheepish that I didn't realise that I could search firebase that simply, but hay. It works!  Just one thing that seems strange is that the recycler view needs to be opened then closed then opened again for the data to show...Any ideas why?

Comment: You're welcome. This is typically an adapter issue but if it isn't the case, just post another fresh question containing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you. Cheers!

Comment: Will do. It's the same adapter that's shown here but I think I understand why it's needed as a different question... What's a MCVE? (as you can guess, I'm kinda new to this).

Comment: `MCVE` stands for `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`.